# How to create new string column in PySpark DataFrame based on values of other columns?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe that has a couple of fields, e.g.:

| Id | Name | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Johnson |
| 2 | Anna | Maria |

I want to create a new column that would mix the values of other comments into a new string. Desired output is:

| Id | Name | Surname | New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Johnson | Hey there John Johnson! |
| 2 | Anna | Maria | Hey there Anna Maria! |

I'm trying to do (pseudocode):

```
df = df.withColumn("New", "Hey there " + Name + " " + Surname + "!")
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: wrap the literal values in `lit()` and the column names in `col()`. concatenation can be done using `concat()`. see [func doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `concat` function or `format_string` like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "New", 
    F.format_string("Hey there %s %s!", "Name", "Surname")
)

df.show(truncate=False)
# +---+----+-------+-----------------------+
# |Id |Name|Surname|New                    |
# +---+----+-------+-----------------------+
# |1  |John|Johnson|Hey there John Johnson!|
# |2  |Anna|Maria  |Hey there Anna Maria!  |
# +---+----+-------+-----------------------+
```

If you prefer using concat:

```
F.concat(F.lit("Hey there "), F.col("Name"), F.lit(" "), F.col("Surname"), F.lit("!"))
```